# VS Code autocomplete in html file for components

Tags: angular, autocomplete, visual-studio-code, settings

I use [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) for my test angular project. I see in some internet lessons they have ability autocomplete with method names or properties declared in `component` in connected to the `component` `html template`.

Could I know how to customize VS code ho have same ability or which plugin I need to install here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's probably the [VS Code Angular Language Service](https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service) extension.